# Redirect to another view (login page) immediately when session expires in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In my MVC application a user can login . If session is expired i want to redirect immediately to login page . I tried this

```
  protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
    }
```

But its not redirecting the page..I can capture session end.. I can see that by putting a break point there. I know its difficult to redirect the page without request from client. Is there any thing i can do??
and i tried this .. in head section of master page i put following code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0015; URL=<%= Url.Action("Index", "Home") %>"/>
```

the code redirected the page after 15 second. But i only want to redirect if the user is not accessed(idle) the page .

Answer (score 2):

Create a Session controller and give it a HasExpired bool method.

Don't refresh the page, use polling and Jquery's setInterval method to call the HasExpired method via ajax.

If HasExpired returns true, redirect (via window.location) to your home page.

Comment: So how does `HasExpired` look like?